# How to migrate security using upgrade management tool in SAP BOBJ?

Tags: migration, report, business-intelligence, business-objects

I am trying to migrate reports from BOBJ 4.1 SP5 Patch 3 from Development to Production using Upgrade management tool.

However after the upgrade is completed, I see that no security for folders or reports is migrated. Is there anything I need to select or the Upgrade management cannot migrate security.

Comment: Do you mean Upgrade Management Tool (UMT) or Promotion Manager (PM)?  UMT will not migrate content between environments of the same version unless a hack is used.

Comment: UMT can migrate content between environments if we use -internal_use_only_noversioncheck  in properties of the tool.

Comment: Yes, that's the hack I referred to.  Keep in mind that it doesn't work in BI4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to "migrate" (publish I said) is Central Management Console > Promotion Management. With this option you can choose whatever you select (folders, access levels, universes, connections...)
Is this what you were looking for?
Best regards

Comment: Using promotion management its difficult to migrate large no of objects 1000+. Thats the reason I am using upgrade management. But it doesnt migrate security.

Comment: I have experience doing that kind of migration: more than 30 universes, more than 1500 users, hundreds of groups..., and the result was right